# How to pass a dependency to a class that implements IEventProcessor(Event Hub)

Tags: castle-windsor, azure-eventhub

I have the following problem.

we use Event Hub . In the following class, we Inherit from IEventProcessor and as you can see we use Service Locator . We can't get it to work with constructor/property injection. It seems that Castle Windsor can't resolve dependencies when the class that aims to inherits from the IEventProcessor. Is that a known issue or there is something I need to do to get it working?

Below is the code :

```
public class EventProcessor : IEventProcessor
{
    private readonly IEventService _eventService;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly Lazy<RetryPolicy> _retryPolicy;
    private readonly IConfigurationProvider _configurationProvider;

    public EventProcessor()
    {
        try
        {
            _eventService = ContainerProvider.Current.Container.Resolve<IEventService>();
            _logger = ContainerProvider.Current.Container.Resolve<ILogger>();
            _configurationProvider =     ContainerProvider.Current.Container.Resolve<IConfigurationProvider>();

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            _logger.WriteError(string.Format("Error occured when intializing EventProcessor: '{0}'", exception));
        }
    }

    public Task OpenAsync(PartitionContext context)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public async Task ProcessEventsAsync(PartitionContext context, IEnumerable<EventData> events)
    {
        var eventsList = events.ToList();
        EventData lastEvent = null;
        foreach (var eventData in eventsList)
        {
            _logger.WriteVerbose(string.Format("Consumming {0} events...", eventsList.Count()));
            _eventService.ProcessEvent(eventData);
            lastEvent = eventData;
        }

        if (lastEvent != null)
        {
            await AzureServiceBusRetryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () => await context.CheckpointAsync(lastEvent));
        }
    }

    public async Task CloseAsync(PartitionContext context, CloseReason reason)
    {
        _logger.WriteInfo("EventHub processor was closed for this reason: " + reason);

        if (reason == CloseReason.Shutdown)
        {
            await AzureServiceBusRetryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () => await context.CheckpointAsync());
        }

    }


}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I'm using Autofac but ran into the same problem.

I solved by implementing the [IEventProcessorFactory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.ieventprocessorfactory.aspx) and using it when registering the processor in the [EventProcessorHost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventprocessorhost%28v=azure.95%29.aspx).

To give an example, my `EventProcessorHost` looks something like this:

```
public class EventHubProcessorHost
{
    private readonly IEventProcessorFactory _eventProcessorFactory;
    private readonly string _serviceBusConnectionString;
    private readonly string _storageConnectionString;
    private readonly string _eventHubName;

    public EventHubProcessorHost(IEventProcessorFactory eventProcessorFactory, string serviceBusConnectionString, string storageConnectionString, string eventHubName)
    {
        _eventProcessorFactory = eventProcessorFactory;
        _serviceBusConnectionString = serviceBusConnectionString;
        _storageConnectionString = storageConnectionString;
        _eventHubName = eventHubName;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        var builder = new ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder(_serviceBusConnectionString)
        {
            TransportType = TransportType.Amqp
        };

        var client = EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(builder.ToString(), _eventHubName);

        try
        {
            var eventProcessorHost = new EventProcessorHost("singleworker",
              client.Path, client.GetDefaultConsumerGroup().GroupName, builder.ToString(), _storageConnectionString);

            eventProcessorHost.RegisterEventProcessorFactoryAsync(_eventProcessorFactory);
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error on send: " + exp.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

And the factory I pass in has a reference to my IoC container:

```
public class MyEventProcessorFactory : IEventProcessorFactory
{
    private readonly IComponentContext _componentContext;

    public MyEventProcessorFactory(IComponentContext componentContext)
    {
        _componentContext = componentContext;
    }

    public IEventProcessor CreateEventProcessor(PartitionContext context)
    {
        return _componentContext.Resolve<IEventProcessor>();
    }
}
```

This allows me to use constructor injection as normal in my `EventProcessor`:

```
public class MyEventProcessor : IEventProcessor
{
    private IFoo _foo;

    public MyEventProcessor(IFoo foo)
    {
        _foo = foo;
    }

    public Task OpenAsync(PartitionContext context)
    {
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public async Task ProcessEventsAsync(PartitionContext context, IEnumerable<EventData> events)
    {
        foreach (var eventData in events)
        {
            // Processing code
        }

        await context.CheckpointAsync();
    }

    public async Task CloseAsync(PartitionContext context, CloseReason reason)
    {
        if (reason == CloseReason.Shutdown)
        {
            await context.CheckpointAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Then I just wire everything up as normal in the Autofac container at start-up:

```
builder.RegisterType<Foo>().As<IFoo>()

builder.RegisterType<MyEventProcessor>().As<IEventProcessor>()

builder.Register(c => new MyEventProcessorFactory(c.Resolve<IComponentContext>())).As<IEventProcessorFactory>();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Don't inject IComponentContext, inject a Func<PartitionContext, IEventProcessor> eventProcessorFactory, and you should be able to call RegisterType<MyEventProcessorFactory>().

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way to inject dependecies using castle windsor. Given your code **ctor-injection** would work with a constructor listing the dependencies as parameters. In your case, this would look sth. like

```
public EventProcessor(IEventService eventService, ILogger logger, IConfigurationProvider configProvider)
{
    try
    {
        this._eventService = eventService;
        this._logger = logger; // however, i suggest using Property injection for that, see next example
        this._configurationProvider = configProvider;

    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        this._logger.WriteError(string.Format("Error occured when intializing EventProcessor: '{0}'", exception));
    }
}
```

You could then resolve the EventProcessor itsself and those dependencies will be injected.

**Property injection** works with public properties. You simply define them like nomal properties and they get injected indepentendly.

```
public ILogger Logger {get; set;}
```

Consider using Castle Windsors way to inject loggers (see [LoggingFacility in Winsdor docs](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Logging-Facility.ashx). Maybe, you want to use NLog or log4net (like me)? --> then there is a ready-to-use nugetpackage (Castle Windor log4net integraton).